# Can I add a PanGestureRecognizer to a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift4, uipangesturerecognizer

Here is my code

```
  var node = SKSpriteNode()
  node.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
  node.color = UIColor.black
  node.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
  self.addChild(whiteBox)

  let myPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panMethod))


   node.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGestureRecognizer)
```

I get this error

> Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'

What is the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
node.inputView?.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: You need to add code to the panMethod for that I believe which could be a question on its own. Let me know if you need more help or feel free to browse some UIPanGestureRecognizer questions